# Input fields (type="number") loose their two-way 'BIND' property of angularjs once their content is changed.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

My problem is pretty simple but elusive in nature. When you will load the index.php, (as localhost using xampp) you will be presented with a simple form. Now there are multiple elements on this form, and it's still a work in progress, so the possibility of multiple bugs is plausible. However, there's this one bug that's really annoying.

**THE PROBLEM:**

> On changing the Due Date element, the content of the following input
>   boxes changes due to the fact that they're bind with it. Now it won't
>   matter how many times you change the due date, because every time the
>   value in the fields will change accordingly, Thanks to angularjs.
>
> The BUG creeps in when you change the value of an input field. Say
>   originally it was 27 and then you changed it to , idk say 10.*** NOW
>   IF YOU CHANGE THE DUE DATE, THE ALTERED INPUT FIELD REMAINS THE SAME
>   *** I.E. WITH VALUE 10, WHEREAS I WANT IT TO CHANGE NEVERTHELESS.
>
> Moreover, if one of you guys is the apotheosis of angularjs coders,
>   and he got some tips for me, I would just like to say..... "I APPRECIATE
>   THAT".

**index.php**

```
    <!-- addService.html -->
<?php
    $version = time();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap and our custon css files) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ctrl-add-service.js"></script>
    <script src="services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="ctrl-add-service">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1 align="center">SERVICE FORM</h1>
            <form role="form" ng-submit="createService()"> 
                <div>
                    <label>Service Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter service name here" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/" required>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Due Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model='dueDate' ng-change="setFields()" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Task Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;" align="center">
                    <label>Period</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value='12' ng-change="setFields()">Annually</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value='6' ng-change="setFields()">Semi-Annually</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value='4' ng-change="setFields()">Quarterly</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="value" value='1' ng-change="setFields()">Monthly</label>
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    <div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Jan</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[0]' ng-required='!fields[0]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Feb</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[1]' ng-required='!fields[1]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Mar</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[2]' ng-required='!fields[2]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Apr</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[3]' ng-required='!fields[3]'></div>
                    </div>

                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>May</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[4]' ng-required='!fields[4]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Jun</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[5]' ng-required='!fields[5]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Jul</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[6]' ng-required='!fields[6]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Aug</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[7]' ng-required='!fields[7]'></div>

                    <div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Sep</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[8]' ng-required='!fields[8]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Oct</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[9]' ng-required='!fields[9]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Nov</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[10]' ng-required='!fields[10]'></div>
                        <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Dec</label><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-disabled='fields[11]' ng-required='!fields[11]'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div  align="center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ctrl-add-service.js (controller)**

```
    // ctrl-add-service.js          Controller for the add service option in the nav bar of the home screen.
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]); 

mainApp.controller('ctrl-add-service',function($scope, DueDateService){

    $scope.value ='1';
    $scope.setFields = function() {
        $scope.date = DueDateService.date($scope.dueDate);
        $scope.fields = DueDateService.fields( DueDateService.month($scope.dueDate), $scope.value);         // first parameter passes month in int, second parameter passes period value in int.
    };
});
```

**services.js (services for the app)**

```
    // services.js          services.js of the account direcotry of the project. It is used by the mainApp.     

//DueDateService

mainApp.service('DueDateService', function(){

    this.month = function(date) {
        var temp = new Date(date);
        month = temp.getMonth();
        console.log(month+1+" is the month");
        return (month+1);
    };

    this.date = function(date) {
        var temp = new Date(date);
        date = temp.getDate();
        console.log(date+" is the date");
        return (date);
    };


    this.fields = function(month,period) {
        var lap = parseInt(period);         // possible values of lap can be [12,6,4,1]
        var iteration = 12/lap;             // possible values of iteration can be [1,2,3,12]       
        var selectedFields = [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];     

        for (var i=1; i<=iteration; i++) {
            if(month>12) {
                month = month - 12;
            }
            selectedFields[month-1]= false;
            month = month + lap;
        }

        return selectedFields;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the `ng-value` to `ng-model` and create an `Array` of your dates, like this:

```
ng-model='dates[0]'
ng-model='dates[1]'
ng-model='dates[2]'
...
```

And your controller would be like this:

```
var date = DueDateService.date($scope.dueDate);
$scope.dates = Array(12).fill(date);
```

See at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/p8O14Y80hCWyNmxnYxbF

Answer (score 0):

In following lines why are you taking ng-value, As far as I think you will have to take ng-model="date" And this will work fine.

see the ng-value usages 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

```
 <div style="display:inline-block;"><label>Jan</label><input type="number"   class="form-control" ng-value='date' ng-model="date" ng-disabled='fields[0]' ng-required='!fields[0]'></div>
```